# Trabalhando com Varias Requisição Flask python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Olá, sou novo no desenvolvimento de aplicações em Python usando o Flask, desenvolvi uma aplicação usando o Python e Flask, hospedei a  aplicação no Google Cloud App Engine, e me deparei com um problema, em alguns momentos quando mais de um usuário esta usando o mesmo recurso da minha aplicação ele esta dando erro, encontrei recentemente um tutorial dando uma dica para habilitar a seguinte linha de comando na minha aplicação

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port), threaded = True)
```

Gostaria de saber se para uma aplicação com um auto volume de requisiçÃo somente este procedimento resolveria o problema ?, o que seria uma boa pratica para este tipo de desenvolvimento ?.

Answer (score 1):

O servidor que vem por defeito no Flask é apenas para testes. Aconselho a usar Apache ou Nginx com o uWSGI ou o FastCGI.

Esta página tem mais informação e tem uma secção sobre Google App Engine: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/deploying/